# How to stop opening documents and pdf files by default app in android programmatically?

Tags: android, dialog

i have created an app for viewing documents and pdf files, when you select a file (for example:sample.pdf or sample.doc) in your mobile, a dialog box will appear showing my app and other apps available for viewing with options on below(just once or always) or (set default). The problem is, Once i have clicked my app with these (always or set default) options in that dialog box, next time when i select a file to read, it automatically opens my app without showing other apps with dialog box options. I tried looking for a solution, but i can't get any ideas, can you guys help me on fixing this problem.

Comment: It's not a problem. It's an android architecture and also the beauty of android.

Comment: So it opens your app by default if you set your app as default. So what exactly you wish to achieve?

Comment: next time when i selected a file it should reappear.

Comment: But you've set your app as the default to open pdf files. The system does not need to ask you again, so the dialog won't be displayed.

Comment: well i know that, is there anyway to reopen dialog.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried looking for a solution

There is no "solution", because there is no problem.

The **user** decided to make your app be the default for this operation. That is the **user's** choice, not yours. If the **user** wants to change that, the **user** can go into Settings and do so (e.g., "Clear Defaults" on your app's screen in the list of installed apps).

Now, in cases where your app is the one starting some other activity, and you want to force a chooser, you can use `Intent.createChooser()` for that. But you cannot force other developers to use `Intent.createChooser()` when they ask Android to view "documents and pdf files" via `ACTION_VIEW`, and you cannot prevent the user from making your app be the default for those operations.

Comment: @vicky: Settings > Apps > (find your app) > Clear Defaults.

Comment: well Clear Defaults is in disabled state when i checked but even after i cleared data and cache in Settings it stil opens my app in default.

Comment: @vicky: Then you will have to poke around on your device and figure out if there is some other area for defaults. HTC, for example, has something else ("App Associations"?) in Settings that impacts some of this.

Comment: wel i tried i can't find anything, i am using Moto E can you give any suggestions.

Comment: @vicky: Uninstall and reinstall your app.

Comment: well in that case i can't ask users to uninstall and reload my app, is there anythere way to remove my app from opening default programmatically.

Comment: @vicky: "i can't ask users to uninstall and reload my app" -- first, those users want your app to be the default. That is why they made it the default. Second, the decision about making your app the default is between the user and Android. You are not involved. "is there anythere way to remove my app from opening default programmatically" -- no.